# GET request to API request give status code of 502. How can I resolve this?

Tags: https, nestjs

I am building an application with nestjs framework. I have created controller and service to fetch data from Http endpoint. Instead of getting the json data I am getting 
`Error: Request failed with status code 502
    at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:237:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)` in the output. The `endpoint is working fine on Google Chrome`. I have integrated my application with Swagger UI. What changes should I make in my code so that I can get data from endpoint?

Here is my service.ts

```
import { Injectable, HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

  configEndPoint: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';

  getData(source: string, productCode: string, vehicleType: string) {
    return this.httpService
      .get(this.configEndPoint)
      .pipe(map(response => response.data.json()));
  }
}
```

Here is my controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Post, Body, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  ApiImplicitHeader,
  ApiOperation,
  ApiResponse,
  ApiUseTags,
} from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { ProductEvent } from '../dto/product-event';
import { MessageService } from '../service/message/message-service';

@Controller('/service/api/message')
export class MessageController {
  source: string;
  productCode: string;
  vehicleType: string;
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

  @Post()
  @ApiUseTags('processor-dispatcher')
  @ApiOperation({ title: 'Generate product message for the SNS topics' })
  async generateMessage(@Body() productEvent: ProductEvent) {


    return JSON.stringify(
      this.messageService.getData(
        this.source,
        this.productCode,
        this.vehicleType,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this happening from localhost or when you have your application hosted somewhere? Are you inside a firewall or something similar? Can you post the entire error that you are getting?

Comment: Yes this is happening on localhost. I am using Swagger UI for GET request. I have update the error message

Comment: What happens when you use cURL or Postman?

Comment: On postman after disabling ssl certificate verification the response is coming as expected. I am using vscode editor

Comment: A 502 is a bad gateway response, so it would seem that there is a problem with the SSL certificate, or there is some sort of firewall blocking your application (though doubtful because Postman is working)

Comment: I am on company network, anything else that I can try?